# Ввод с консоли Java

Tags: java

```
 import java.util.Scanner;  
 public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    int a = 3, b = 0;
      for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++)
       {
       for (int j = 1; j <= (a + i - 1); j++)
        {
        if (j <= (a - i))
          {
          System.out.print('.');
          b++;
          }
        else
        {
        System.out.print('*');
        }
         }
         for (int j = 1; j <= b; j++)
        {
        System.out.print('.');
         }
        b = 0;
    System.out.println();
         }
    }
}
Эта программа рисует такой треугольник 
..*..
.***.
*****
```

Как получить такой же треугольник через ввод с консоли. Например пользователь указал число 5, значит будет нарисовано 5 таких треугольник. Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Ввод с консоли осуществляется вот так:
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
И далее выбирайте подходящий вам метод, например, чтобы получить получить число используется: scan.nextInt();